# How to prevent Matlab udp/fread from convertig raw byte data to double

Tags: matlab, udp

I'm trying to read encoded raw data from UDP and to pass it to my custom MEX file for decoding. Now what I get when I use `fread` to read data from my UDP port are doubles. Also, the documentation for [udp/fread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/fread.html) tells that

> By default, numeric values are returned in double precision arrays

however, what it doesn't tell is how I can prevent this conversion and how to get the raw byte values instead. I have no use of floating values and would have to convert back in my MEX file, which would cause unnecessary overhead.

EDIT:
As requested, here is a little example.

```
u = udp();
u.LocalPort = 3333;
fopen( u );
data = fread( u, 10, 'uint8' );
fclose( u );
```

Suppose you send via this little Python script:

```py
import time
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 3333
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE, "utf-8"), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    time.sleep(.100)
```

Just as the documentation of udp/fread tells, this treats input as `uint8` and returns doubles. However, in contrast to the [fread documentation for reading from files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html), the UDP version seems to have no understanding of `*` or `=>` syntax to specify output types.

btw: I'm using R2017b, maybe this also makes a difference.

Comment: Would anybody elaborate on why this was voted down?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `'precision'` input for `fread` ([docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html#btp1twt-1-precision)):

```
Form of the precision Input   Description

source                        Input values are of the class specified by source.
                              Output matrix A is class double.
                              Example: 'int16'

source=>output                Input values are of the class specified by source.
                              The class of the output matrix, A, is specified by output.
                              Example: 'int8=>char'

*source                       The input values and the output matrix, A, are of
                              the class specified by source. For bitn or ubitn precisions, 
                              the output has the smallest class that can contain the input.
                              Example: '*ubit18'
                              This is equivalent to 'ubit18=>uint32'
```

So you should be able to use

```
A = fread( fid, 2, '*int16' ); % Use correct size instead of 2 depending on your type
```

Comment: I suppose you mean `'*uint8'`, right? That's also what I tried, but I am getting an error, so I thought I misunderstood the documentation: _Error using udp/fread (line 212)
Invalid PRECISION specified. Type 'instrhelp fread' for more information.

Error in readFrames (line 23)
            data = fread( u, u.BytesAvailable, '*uint8' )_

Comment: Whatever data type you want, I chose an arbitrary example... Without a [mcve] it's hard to tell why you are getting an error. What if you specified `1` instead of `u.BytesAvailable`? If you're forcing it to be `uint8` anyway then it should only be 1 byte.

Comment: Funny thing is, what I just realized, that the `SIZE` parameter seems to be ignored. Instead it seems like _one_ whole datagram is read, no matter what I specify. Btw. the documentation you linked in your post is referring to the file version of `fread`. The one I'm talking about is [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/fread.html).